# Error passing parameter from lightning component to flow

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, visual-workflow, aura

A controller with the below works fine:

```
init : function (component) {
        var flow = component.find('flowData');
        flow.startFlow('OppAssignmentProcess');
}
```

A controller with the below errors out (see error below)

```
init : function (component) {
        var flow = component.find('flowData');
        var inputVariables = [
            { name : "recordid", type : "Text", value: 'HardcodedIdIKnowIsValid' }
        ];


        flow.startFlow('OppAssignmentProcess', inputVariables);
}
```

> Error: Unfortunately, there was a problem. Please try again. If the
>   problem continues, get in touch with your administrator with the error
>   ID shown here and any other related details. Error ID: 259365525-31105
>   (-649484994)

Error From the VF page that wraps this (done to allow linking from a formula field):

> This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Error in
>   $A.getCallback() [[object Object]] Callback failed:
>   serviceComponent://ui.interaction.runtime.components.controllers.FlowRuntimeController/ACTION$runInterview
>   Callback failed:
>   serviceComponent://ui.interaction.runtime.components.controllers.FlowRuntimeController/ACTION$runInterview
>   Failing descriptor: {js://flowruntime:utils.action}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is a `Text` data type in flow.

Try changing to string type, eg:

```
var inputVariables = [
    { name : "recordid", type : "String", value: "HardcodedIdIKnowIsValid" }
];
```

Also, it's probably a good idea to made sure you quotes are all the same type in the JSON (I doubt that this would crash anything though)

Comment: That did it. Thank you!